# css how to align absolute positioned child element to the right of fluid width parent

Tags: html, css, alignment, absolute, fluid-layout

I'm trying to put some background images that are part of my layout to the left and the right of my main content `div`.

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jozcbboo/), as you can see giving the element a right margin of 0px doesn't affect the layout, giving it a left margin affects the layout, but since the width is variable I can't know the width of the wrapper div beforehand (without using Javascript which I don't want to).

css

```
 #wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: grey;
}

#leftLayoutCol {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    background-color: green;
}

#rightLayoutCol {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

#main {
   padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
   background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftLayoutCol">
    </div>
    <div id="rightLayoutCol">
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following attribute.

```
#rightLayoutCol {
    right: 0;
}
```

Since `#wrapper` is `position: fixed` it already gives a new positioning context.